# Removing HTML tags from string except hyperlinks and line breaks?

Tags: c#, html, regex, text

I have strings of HTML markup along with normal text written between it, what I want to do is to remove all HTML tags except hyperlinks and line breaks so that it will look like normal notepad style text but formatted (i.e with line breaks so it remains readable) and hyperlinks to ensure all external links remain visible for user to click.

I have tried some regex solutions but they completely eliminate all HTML markup which I don't want.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). it seems be useful for your issue.